# Remove-spdeletedsite will raise the following error "unable to find the specified path"

Tags: 2013, site-collection, central-administration, administration

I run the following command:-

```
get-spdeletedsite
```

which showed me a list of deleted site collections, now i run the following to remove the deleted sites as follow:-

```
remove-spdeletedsite 032**********
```

but i got the following error :-

> unable to find the specified path

[image]

now i try  to run the following script :-

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$CorruptSites = "http://***/sites/***"

Function DeleteCorruptSite
{
param($CorruptSite)
Write-Host $CorruptSite : -foreground red
$site = Get-SPSite $CorruptSite
$siteId = $site.Id
$siteDatabase = $site.ContentDatabase 
$siteDatabase.ForceDeleteSite($siteId, $false, $false)
Write-Host --Deleted from Content DB -foreground green
}
foreach ($CorruptSite in $CorruptSites)
{
 DeleteCorruptSite $CorruptSite
}
```

but i got the following exception also:-

```
http://***/sites/*** :
Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url: http://***/sites/***.
At C:\Users\***\Desktop\1.ps1:10 char:9
+ $site = Get-SPSite $CorruptSite
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite
```

so can anyone adivce on this please ?i remember that i tried to remove this site collection using the central administration UI. but it raised an exception and the site content database and site collection administrator became empty,, so is there a way to remove corrupted deleted site collection ?

Comment: little confusing, if you are seeing the site collection  using get-spdeletedsites then how can you see that in the central admin....Only deleted sites showed in that command. you tryong to remove the teamout site collection...did you try remove-spdeletedsite /sites/teamout

Comment: You could try to detach and attach the DB, that was one way to clear corrupted sites in the past when powershell or stsadm wouldn't work.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i tried the following "remove-spdeletedsite <i type the site id >" . now i type "remove-spdeletedsite /sites/teamout" but i got the same error "Unable to find the specified file."

Comment: @EricAlexander as i know detach/attach DB are done to web applications and not site collections ? is this correct, as inside my web application i have other site collections ... so how i can process this?

Comment: try this http://bfy.tw/r8c

Comment: @EricAlexander as i mentioned before that detach/attach a DB is done to the whole web application. while in my case i want to detach/attach the DB to certain site collection only.. so is this possible ?